# WordPress create profile pages for users

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to create a profile page for every user that is registered on my WordPress site? I need a feature that allows each registered user to fill in his profile - name, address, email, add photos. Then this data is populated to a user's profile page using a template so when anyone goes to, e.g. mysite.com/users/johndoe, he sees the user's profile page with all information. Thanks.

Comment: Belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

**[WordPress Users Plugin](http://kempwire.com/wordpress-users-plugin)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Wordpress Users Plugin, along with WP Members. I've managed to customize the WP-Members profile page in order to show an image and additional information and i have created a page with WP Users Plugin witch it shows a list of users. The problem now is to also customize users page (instead of a list, to show more details). Thanks for the help